# How to link different but similar structs in a linked circular list?

Tags: algorithm, go, pointers, circular-list, knuth

I'm trying to implement Knuth's Algorithm X but I'm having trouble with generating the linked list. My column headers and data points are different types, but similar in build.

```
type ListObject interface{}

type Data struct {
    L, R, U, D, C *ListObject
}

type Column struct {
    L, R, U, D, C *ListObject
    Size          int
    Name          string
}
```

and this is the very WIP code, where i encountered the problem:

```
func CreateLinkedList(sparceMatrix [][]int) Column {
    masterHeader := new(Column)
    currentHeader := masterHeader
    for i, col := range sparceMatrix[0] {
    }
    currentHeader.R = masterHeader

    return masterHeader
}
```

The bit the compiler dislikes is the currentHeader.R = masterHeader bit.

The variables in the Data struct are adjacent dada structs (Left, Right), but U(p) and D(own) could also be a Column object.

I thought about using a interface for a ListObject struct, as you an see, but the compiler does not like that. Other than that, i haven gotten a good idea to the solution. Worse case scenario, i have to make every struct in the list the same type.

Any advice would be appreciated, new to programming.

Comment: Make data and columns the same type. Use https://medium.com/@reetas/clean-ways-of-adding-new-optional-fields-to-a-golang-struct-99ae2fe9719d to make size and name optional. Have default values on size and name that clearly indicate that data is not a header. Now it is easy to make your linked list with both data and columns together.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, pointer to interface (like `*ListObject`) is practically never what you want. That is the cause of your error `cannot use masterHeader (variable of type *Column) as *ListObject value in assignment: *Column does not implement *ListObject (type *ListObject is pointer to interface, not interface)`. Change every instance of `*ListObject` to `ListObject` and everything will go more smoothly.

The other error is `cannot use masterHeader (variable of type *Column) as Column value in return statement`, which is just as it says; you're creating a `*Column` (pointer to column), but your function signature says you're returning a `Column`. Likely you want to change the function signature to return `*Column` here.

Comment: But the list object that im recording, that can still be a pointer then?

Comment: Yes, the value inside the interface can be a pointer.

Comment: this seemed to work for that error. I now have a problem of not being able to access the fields in a loop (interface has no field or method). so it seems im back to square one :D if you got any suggestions for that, id take them :D but thank you anyway

Comment: You could give your interface methods and use them for navigating the linked list instead of direct field access.